# How do I play slow motion videos from iPhone?

Tags: windows-7, video

I took some slow motion videos on my iPhone 6s.

I then used the Google Photos iOS app to upload them to the Google Photos online albums. When I watch the videos online (using Chrome on Windows 7) they still show the slow motion effect.

But when I choose "Download" from the top right menu on the video page, and try to play it with VLC, the video I get is a normal speed one.

How can I play the slow motion version on my PC?

Comment: What are you using to view the videos after you've downloaded them? The videos downloaded *do* include the slow-motion effect (the metadata needed to show it, to be precise), so it's not a problem with Google Photos. For example, when I play them using QuickTime, they still show the slow-motion effect.

Comment: See also: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204064

Comment: @slhck I'm trying to play it with VLC. But also tried with Windows Media Player and iTunes. Same result

Comment: VLC player can reproduce at 0.1x speed, which is roughly 24fps of the slo-mo video. But you can only control this with keyboard shortcut. Something along the lines of "[" and "]"